# Kubernetes loadbalancer service vs cloud loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud, load-balancing

In Kubernetes configuration, for external service component we use:

```
type: LoadBalancer
```

If we have k8s cluster running inside a cloud provider like AWS, which provides it own loadbalancer, how does all this work then? Do we need to configure so that one of these loadbalancers is not active?

Comment: Normally your k8 loadbalancer will be using the ip address of the cloud loadbalancer and its the cloud load balancer doing all the hardwork

Comment: My understanding is that flow of request is from cloud layer to k8s cluster. So doesn't it mean that cloud LB must use ip address of k8 LB?

Comment: Normally the cloud loadbalancer will be configured with all the nodes of the k8 cluster.  you dont have to do this work yourself, normally (at least in azure) if i create a k8 service with type loadbalancer, azure will create the cloud LB for me and configure it with all the node addresses then give that cloud LB address to the k8 LB. It acts and does all the hardwork as the LB and the k8 cluster just uses the cloud LB as its IP

Comment: Behind the scenes, when you create a LoadBalancer service, it uses a cloud LoadBalancer; internally K8s creates NodePorts services to glue the LoadBalancer request with the right apps in your cluster; so the Cloud LoadBalancer get all that information mapped with request to the right endpoints. All that process is automated and internal to your cloud provider 

Answer (score 1):

AWS now takes over the open source project: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller

It works with EKS(easiest) clusters as well as [non-EKS clusters](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/deploy/installation/)(need to install aws vpc cni etc to make `IP` target mode work, which is required if you have a peered VPC environment.)

This is the official/native solution of managing AWS LB(aka ELBv2) resources(App ELB, Network ELB) using K8s. Kubernetes in-tree controller always reconciles `Service` object with `type: LoadBalancer`

Once configured correctly, AWS LB controller will manage the following 2 types of LBs:

1. Application LB, via Kubernetes `Ingress` object. It operates on L7 and provides features related to HTTP
2. Network LB, via Kubernetes `Service` object with [correct annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/guide/service/nlb/). It operates on L4 and provides less features but claimed MUCH higher throughput.

To my knowledge, this works best when used with `external-dns` together -- it automatically updates your Route53 record with your LB A records thus makes the whole service discovery solution k8s-y.

Also in general, should prevent usage of classic ELB, as it's marked as deprecated by AWS.